# Value of a textbox in silverlight + MVVM

Tags: mvvm, textbox

I have a xaml names Customer.xaml like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="customview" >
   <StackPanel x:Name="CustomPanel" > 
      <TextBox x:Name="CustomText" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid
```

Using MVVM I have created ICustomerviewmodel and Customerviewmodel like this:

```
public interface ICustomerviewmodel 
{
     ICommand SaveClientCommand { get; }
}

public class Customerviewmodel : ICustomerviewmodel , INotifyPropertyChanged
{
   ......
   private void ExecuteSaveClient()
   {
     //
   }
```

My question is how I could get the value of 
inside the function ExecuteSaveClient() to save this?

Comment: Customer.xaml:       <TextBox x:Name="KlientText"

Comment: How to get the value of <TextBox x:Name="KlientText" inside the function ExecuteSaveClient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You should declare a string property in your view model say:

  `public string CustomText { get; set; }`
- Assign datacontext of customview to be your viewmodel int the constructor, hope this grid is in a UserControl or Window:

  `this.customview.DataContext = new CustomerViewModel();`
- Bind to that property:

  `<TextBox x:Name="CustomText" Text="{Binding CustomText}"/>`
- Implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/How-to-implement-INotifyPropertyChanged-interface.aspx), if TwoWay binding and notification are required.

Read more into silverlight databinding [here](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Silverlight_DataBinding_Basics.aspx).

Comment: Sorry that I'am not clear about the question. I'll try again.

Comment: I want the user to enter some text in TextBox and press the Save button. All I want to do is how to get the new text and save it in the ExecuteSaveClient() methodes.

Comment: Follow the steps I have given, I believe ExecuteSaveClient() is attached to SaveClientCommand and that command is bound to your SaveButton. If all these are done correctly you should be able to access CustomText property with the latest textbox value in ExecuteSaveClient() method.

Comment: OK. I'll try it later tonight. Thank you for all help. I'll let you know if it is working. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Use a binding expression:

```
<TextBox x:Name="CustomText" Text="{Binding TestProperty}" />
```

Where `TestProperty` is a public property on your view model which is the current `DataContext`.

If you wish to update the value in your view model, and have this reflected in the view, then the setter of the `TestProperty` property should invoke the `PropertyChanged` event on the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface implemented by your view model.

Comment: Your question code doesn't show that, can you add that code in. Do you have a Name property on your view model? Have you set the DataContext of the view to an instance of your view model?